# "node contents" key not working with "\node at"

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

When I try to use something like

```
\node[node contents={Test}] at (0,0){};
```

an error is throw : `Use of \@next doesn't match its definition.`

To make it works, I can change the syntax to `\path ... node`, or use `at` key, or use a `font=` hack.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % \node[node contents={Test}] at (0,0){}; % <- not working
    % \node[node contents={Test}] at (1,0); % <- not working

    \path (0,0) node[node contents={Test}];
    \path (1,0) node[node contents={Test}]{};
    \node[node contents={Test}, at={(2,0)}];
    \node[node contents={Test}, at={(3,0)}]{};
    \node[font={Test}] at (4,0){};        
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**My question is : Is this the normal behavior, or a bug ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the expected behavior and it's documented on page 215 of the manual (italics are mine for emphasis):

> `/tikz/node contents=<node contents>`
>
> *When the option is used inside the options of a node, the parsing of
> the node stops immediately after the end of the option block*. In
> particular, the option block cannot be followed by further option
> blocks or curly braces (or, rather, these do not count as part of the
> node specification.) Also note that the node contents may not contain
> fragile stuff since the catcodes get fixed upon reading the options.

Comment: Thanks ! I should read the manual before to ask ;) But why this limitation ? Why using `font=` key works better than the designed key ?

Comment: @Kpym You're welcome. I have to leave now but latter I'll add some remarks.

Comment: @Kpym I gave a quick look at `tikz.code.tex`. the argument for `node contents` is assigned to `\tikz@node@content` which basically is the last thing the parser scans to know when a node path ends; this justifies the restrictions about its use. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I already have shown in my question that `at` option works.